# calculate relative performance in python on daily stock price data

Tags: python

DataFrame 'MasterFile' includes

```
##Index, Date, CompanyA, CompanyB, Company C
##0, 2019-07-26, 100, 25, 38
##1, 2019-07-25, 99, 24, 37
```

I have 6 records (-5 workdays in the excel) and the Company A, B and C datapoints represent daily closing stock prices

My goal is to create a new data frame that has daily relative stock price performance from the earliest date (in this case the last row). Therefore the DataFrame will look identical to DataFrame 'MasterFile' above, with the exception that only records from the selected date (for example 2019-07-19 which is 6 records) would show up, and the data would be calculated (for each company individually) as [StockPrice] / [Stock Price_selected date] - 1

so in the case above for Company A the formula (if i think about it from an excel perspective would be)

```
##Index, Date, Company A
##0, 2019-07-26, [StockPrice_19-7-26] / [StockPrice_19-7-19]-1
##0, 2019-07-25, [StockPrice_19-7-25] / [StockPrice_19-7-19]-1
##0, 2019-07-24, [StockPrice_19-7-24] / [StockPrice_19-7-19]-1
##0, 2019-07-23, [StockPrice_19-7-23] / [StockPrice_19-7-19]-1
##0, 2019-07-22, [StockPrice_19-7-22] / [StockPrice_19-7-19]-1
##0, 2019-07-19, [StockPrice_19-7-19] / [StockPrice_19-7-19]-1.
```

Comment: more or less: `df["Company A"] = df / (df["Company A"][ df['Date'] == '2019-07-19' ] - 1)`

Comment: Thanks Furas i get an error - cannot perform __truediv__ with this index type: DatetimeIndex

Comment: it could be `df["Company A"] = df["Company A"] / (...)` to work with single column

Answer (score 0):

I use example with dates as strings so it may need changes

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2019-07-26', 100, 25, 38],
    ['2019-07-25',  99, 24, 37],
    ['2019-07-24', 100, 50, 50],
    ['2019-07-19',   5,  2,  2],
], columns=['Date', 'Company A', 'Company B', 'Company C'])

print(df)
```

---

For single column I can get value and convert to `int` or `float`

```
value_A = df['Company A'][df['Date'] == '2019-07-19'] # all values
value_A = value_A.iloc[0] # only first

print('value A:', value_A)
```

And then I can calculate for all rows

```
df['Company A'] = df['Company A'] / (value_A-1)

print(df)
```

---

For many columns I can do the same

```
values = df[['Company A', 'Company B', 'Company C']][df['Date'] == '2019-07-19'] # all values
values = values.iloc[0] # only first

print('values:', values)
```

And then calculate in the same way

```
df[['Company A', 'Company B', 'Company C']] = df[['Company A', 'Company B', 'Company C']] / (values - 1)

print(df)
```

Result for many rows

```
         Date  Company A  Company B  Company C
0  2019-07-26      25.00       12.5       38.0
1  2019-07-25      24.75       12.0       37.0
2  2019-07-24      25.00       25.0       50.0
3  2019-07-19       1.25        1.5        2.0
```

---

**EDIT:** the same little shorter

```
columns = ['Company A', 'Company B', 'Company C']

values = df[columns][df['Date'] == '2019-07-19']
values = values.iloc[0]

print('values:', values)

df[columns] = df[columns] / (values - 1)

print(df)
```